# How to automatically remove text from images?

Tags: image-processing, image

I'd like to remove the text in the center of images automatically. To use `Inpaint[]`, you need a mask, but I don't have one. So really the problem is:

**How to build a mask for an image that contains a known overlaid piece of text?**

Here are some example inputs:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why can't you post code instead of images? You've been a member here long enough, no?

Comment: How do you know it's a watermark and not a photo of words floating in the sky?

Comment: "a known logo" and "I don't have the mask" are at least a partial contradiction

Comment: Let me clarify, I know the logo but not the holography into the image, I don't know its location, orientation, or sizing.

Comment: ... are we at all concerned that the primary utility of such a tool would be using images without the owners' consent?

Comment: @DanielGriscom quite right - I've edited the question considerably in an attempt to sort this out a bit.

Comment: @blochwave I agree on censoring this kind of questions. [**We should also forbid talking about forks and shoelaces**](http://murderpedia.org/male.C/c/culshaw-paul.htm)

Comment: Thanks for this question (and the answers). I want to remove place name information from a US government-made map to use in a report with my own data on top of it. US government maps are public domain. I'm sure there are hundreds of other legitimate uses as well. Don't assume the intent is illegal just because that's the only usage your limited imagination can think of.

Comment: this could actually be really useful for medical teaching. If teaching all patient records (ct, x-ray etc) have to be anonymized. its a laborious process and this could really change things!

Answer (score 59):

> ### PLEASE NOTE
>
> There is a reason why watermarks are there in the first place - **to
>   prevent unauthorised reuse of images**.  For more information on the
>   issues around removing watermarks from images, this [Wikimedia
>   article](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Wikilegal/Removal_of_watermarks_from_Commons_images)
>   is just one of many useful resources.

The answer below is intended as an exercise in automatically removing text from an image using the inpainting technique. The first part of this answer assumes an unknown text overlay using binarization. The second part of the answer attempts to deal with a known overlay image but unknown position, using image correlation.

---

### Part 1 - Unknown overlay text, unknown position

For scenarios where the text is a given colour that differs a lot from the rest of the image, this is a job for [`ChanVeseBinarize[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChanVeseBinarize.html). It even works fairly well with translucent text - here's an example with a bit of translucent white text, using a *Mathematica* test image:

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyJTe.png"]

(* This is where parameters become important *)
binimg = ChanVeseBinarize[image, White, {Automatic, 0.12}, MaxIterations -> 1000];

(* Now we can create the mask *)
maskimg = Dilation[DeleteSmallComponents[binimg, 4], 2.5];
```

And finally the inpainting, making use of the method options to improve the result. It introduces a few artifacts due to an imperfect mask (for example, look at the red edge of the nose), but it's not bad given the text was translucent to start off with. With fully-white text, it's much better.

```
Inpaint[image, maskimg, Method -> {"TextureSynthesis", "MaxSamples" -> 1200}, MaxIterations -> 500]
```

[image]

---

### Part 2 - Known overlay text, unknown position

This deals with a known piece of overlay text, and makes use of [`ImageCorrelate[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageCorrelate.html). Here I make no change to the size or orientation of the overlay, but if you look in the documentation of `ImageCorrelate[]` under "Generalizations and Extensions" you'll see an example of finding rotated occurrences of a template.

```
(* The test image is ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}] *)

overlay = Graphics@Text[Style["I love stackexchange", FontFamily -> "Arial", 
    FontSize -> 32, Bold, White, Opacity[0.8]]];

(* Or you can just import an image I've already prepared *)
compositeimage = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJEWm.png"]
```

Then we use `ImageCorrelate[]` to find the most likely position for the text in the image, and `MaxDetect` to extract its position (the white dot).

```
corrimage = ImageAdjust@ImageCorrelate[compositeimage, Binarize@overlay];
maxdetect = MaxDetect[ImageAdjust@DistanceTransform@Binarize[corrimage, 0.9]];
maxpos = Flatten@PixelValuePositions[maxdetect, 1];

(* This combines the overlay into a mask at the correct position *)
blankimage = Image@ConstantArray[0, ImageDimensions@compositeimage];
maskimage = ImageCompose[blankimage, Binarize@overlay, maxpos];
(* Dilation important to ensure full coverage of the mask *)
maskimage = Dilation[maskimage, 2];
```

Finally we can construct a mask from this information and inpaint. Here the performance is much better than above, because the mask is better.

```
Inpaint[compositeimage, maskimage, 
 Method -> {"TextureSynthesis", "MaxSamples" -> 1200}, 
 MaxIterations -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is very earnest.But is off track I think,the original question is the fontfamily and its contents is known,but the oriention,size and position is unknown.Then the questioner want to remove it.

Comment: Please consider not helping people steal images.

Comment: @DavidRicherby thanks, I've reworked it as best as I can.

Comment: When I try to use ImageAlign,It happen something unhappy:
pic=ExampleData[{"TestImage","Lena"}];
watertext=Image@Graphics@Text[Style["Welcome to China",Blue,30,FontFamily->"Arial"]];
waterimage=Show[pic,Graphics@Text[Style["Welcome to China",Blue,30,FontFamily->"Arial"],{100,400},Automatic,{1,1}]]//Image;
ali=ImageAlign[waterimage,watertext,TransformationClass->"Rigid"];
ImageCompose[ali,{waterimage,0.4}]

Comment: @DavidRicherby I joined this site just to say this: Shut up. The tape recorder wasn't the death of music industry, the VCR not the death of the movie industry and the ability to remove text from images will not be the end of the copyright-on-images thing.

Comment: @AlecTeal And shoplifting won't be the end of grocery stores. But that doesn't mean we should facilitate shoplifting.

Comment: Folks, I log on one sunny Sunday afternoon to find *eight* flags on these comments. I think you all need to take a breath, and please also realise that Mathematica.SE is a reasonably relaxed stack exchange. We moderators do not usually expect to get flags about comments being "too chatty".  I recognise that the question could be interpreted as enabling watermark removal, but there are legitimate uses of the technique as well.

Answer (score 12):

Here's an alternative approach that uses the functionality of `ImageAlign[]` to remove the watermark.

```
pic = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
watertext = 
 Image@Graphics@
   Text[Style["Welcome to China", Blue, 30, FontFamily -> "Arial"]]
```

[image]

```
waterimage = 
 Show[pic, 
   Graphics@
    Text[Style["Welcome to China", Blue, 30, 
      FontFamily -> "Arial"], {130, 400}]] // Image
```

[image]

```
ali = ImageAlign[waterimage, watertext, 
   TransformationClass -> "Perspective"];
ImageCompose[ali, {waterimage, 0.4}]
```

[image]

```
mask = ali // ChanVeseBinarize[#, Blue] & // Dilation[#, 3] &;
Inpaint[waterimage, mask, Method -> "TextureSynthesis"]
```

[image]