# How do I remove text from an image?

Tags: image-processing, image, text, ocr

[image]

I want to remove "the worst of times" from this image. How do I do that? I don't have a preference to how it's done.

Comment: Like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzSwm.png

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Do you want it done specifically with text recognition?

Comment: Please add more specifics.

Comment: closely related [How to automatically remove text from images?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95512/how-to-automatically-remove-text-from-images)

Answer (score 6):

Maybe something like this:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Jl54.png"]

text = TextRecognize @ img

del = {"the worst", "of times"};

Rasterize[#, RasterSize -> 1000, ImageSize -> ImageDimensions @ img]& @
   Style[#, FontFamily -> "Times"]& @
 StringReplace[
  text, {del[[1]] -> StringPadRight["", StringLength @ del[[1]]], 
   del[[2]] -> StringPadRight["", StringLength @ del[[2]]]}]
```

[image]