# remove the text of the images

Tags: image-processing, image

I want to remove the text of the image in Mathematica. Can someone help me remove the text from the image?
[image]

Comment: [remove-text-from-images](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95512/how-to-automatically-remove-text-from-images)